# I2C sensor hogs the bus with empty write commands

Tags: i2c

I am trying to read data from a pair of TLE493-W2B6 magnetic position sensors [[1](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-TLE493D-W2B6-DataSheet-v01_20-EN.pdf?fileId=5546d46261764359016189ec158943a4), [2](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-TLE493D-W2B6-UM-v01_01-UserManual-v01_11-EN.pdf?fileId=5546d46261ff5777016229accba436e2)] with Arduino over I2C. I can read from each sensor individually, using the Arduino library from the manufacturer [[3](https://github.com/Infineon/TLE493D-3DMagnetic-Sensor), with corrections from [4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57358959/compilation-error-in-example-for-infineons-tle493d-w2b6-sensor)], but when I try to read both sensors, I can only read the first sensor I initialize. The first sensor then issues empty write commands, and the second sensor NACKs when I try to address it. The sensors have different factory-programmed addresses, and they are connected to the same I2C bus on a PCB with pullup resistors. When I scan the bus for I2C devices, both sensors show up (ie they both ACK their own address).

How do I read both sensors over I2C with Arduino?

Code for reading both sensors:

```
#include <Tle493d_w2b6.h>

Tle493d_w2b6 sensor_A0 = Tle493d_w2b6(Tle493d_w2b6::MASTERCONTROLLEDMODE, Tle493d_w2b6::TLE493D_W2B6_A0);
Tle493d_w2b6 sensor_A1 = Tle493d_w2b6(Tle493d_w2b6::MASTERCONTROLLEDMODE, Tle493d_w2b6::TLE493D_W2B6_A1);

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  while (!Serial);

  sensor_A1.begin();
  sensor_A0.begin();
}

void loop() {
  sensor_A1.updateData();
  Serial.print(sensor_A1.getX());
  Serial.print(", ");
  Serial.print(sensor_A1.getY());
  Serial.print(", ");
  Serial.println(sensor_A1.getZ());

  sensor_A0.updateData();
  Serial.print(sensor_A0.getX());
  Serial.print(", ");
  Serial.print(sensor_A0.getY());
  Serial.print(", ");
  Serial.println(sensor_A0.getZ());

  delay(500);

}
```

Here is what the average cycle looks like:

[image: Oscilloscope capture of sensors 1 and 2]

1. (0.005ms) Read the first six registers of sensor A1.

   - Address frame =  0x22
   - R/W = R
   - Data frames = FF 00 FF 80 F1 1F 6A~ (this is as expected)
2. (0.828ms) Library sends empty write command to sensor A1?

   - Address frame =  0x22
   - R/W = W
   - Data frames = empty
3. (2.281ms) Attempt to read the first six registers of sensor A0, address is NACK'd, no data is returned.

   - Address frame =  0x35~
   - R/W = R
   - Data frames = empty
4. (2.353ms) Library sends another empty write command to sensor A1.

   - Address frame =  0x22
   - R/W = W
   - Data frames = empty

Comment: There seems to be something wrong at the fundamental I2C protocol execution. There are no empty writes or reads in the library (I think this isn't even possible with the `Wire` library, which is used there). Also the spike at the end of the 0x44 write span (as in the image) is suspicious. The sensor is operating at 3.3V. Do you use a 3.3V Arduino? You didn't specify

Comment: I was using the 5V rail on the Arduino to power the sensors. I replaced the sensors, and I am now powering them off the Arduino's 3.3V rail, with the Arduino's internal I2C pullups disabled and external pullups to the 3.3V. Still having the same issue. I am going to try sending bits with an I2C host adapter, to see if it's a problem on the Arduino side.

Comment: By default the sensor adds trigger bits to the register address, so I'm having some trouble communicating with the device. I'm having some trouble getting the right initialization sequence.